# calling an object in object using new

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello there my second question here ive been trying to create a clicker started over from scratch and this time using design patterns but ive been stuck on this :

```
var Store_Item = {
    name: '',
    amount: 0,        
     cost: {
        Costs: 0
        /* could ask different stuff here  */
     },
     Get: {
         GetAmount: 0
     }
};
  Store_Item = $.makeArray(Store_Item);
  Store_Item[1] = new Store_Item {Name:"name", amount:0};
```

But i want to call Cost or Get like this :

```
Store_Item[1] = new Store_Item {Name: "name", amount:0, cost:{Costs: 3}};
```

Like that

Comment: `Store_Item = $.makeArray(Store_Item);` <-- HUH? What are you doing here

Comment: converting it to an array ?

Comment: Why do you do that ? You already have an object, use it

Comment: Well i dont want to store information in the object so i converted it to an array so i can use it multiple times ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't understand the concept of Instantiable Classes in JavaScript...

On you code you create an object, and you try to create multi instance of it.. But you can, you just can use this one.

If you want do that, you must set your object like that :

```
// Define
var myObject = function(arg) {
    this.myProperty = arg;
    this.myMethode = function () {
        return this.myProperty;
    }
}

// Init
var object_a = new myObject("a");
var object_b = new myObject("b");

// Use
alert( object_a.myMethode() );
```

In your case:

```
// Define object
var Stored_item = function(name, amount) {
    this._name = name;
    this._amount = amount;
    this._costs = [];

    this.add_cost = function(cost){
       this._costs.push(cost);
    }
}

// Create array list
var stored_items = [];

// Add objects on array
stored_items.push( new Stored_item("name A", 100) );
stored_items.push( new Stored_item("name B", 550) );

// Using first object (with "name A" name)
stored_items[0].add_cost(52);
```

Comment: lol this is exactly what i tried to prevent, No you are right i dont understand the full concept of it, thats why i am asking questions here to learn from it. but i want to make an array of it so i can use the same object with the same variable like this

 Store_Item[1] = new Store_Item {Name: "name1", amount:1, cost:{Costs: 3}};
 Store_Item[2] = new Store_Item {Name: "name2", amount:3, cost:{Costs: 100}};

So i can prevent using 2 lines

Comment: Well still not really what i'm trying to do in this case i couldve done something like this : var Store_Item = {
    name: '',
    amount: 0,
    Costs: 0,
    GetAmount: 0
};
  Store_Item[1] = new Store_Item{name:'blabla', etc};
But since im trying to get things organized i want to acces cost and Get in the same new Store_Item

Comment: These are perfectly good answers! You are simply attempting something that is simply not necessary!

Comment: Those are still not my answers i want to keep it as short as possible else i could've used 2 lines and im trying to keep it at 1 line, so 1 line to create 1 new object

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if the statement:

Store_Item = $.makeArray(Store_Item);

was meant to create an array with a single element, it should be:

```
Store_Item = [Store_Item];
```

$.makeArray has a completely different purpose.

Now if the "statement":

```
Store_Item[1] = new Store_Item {Name:"name", amount:0};
```

Is meant to append a copy of the first object with some properties changed, this will do the job:

```
Store_Item[1] = $.extend({}, Store_Item[0], {name:"name", amount:0});
```

etc...

Is this of any help?

Comment: hmm well first i wanted to make an array of the object Store_Item so i added $.makeArray(Store_Item); so the Object Store_Item was converted and i could use Store_Item[1] etc but Store_Item[2] should have completely different values so an array would be good for that and i could loop through it by using Store_Item[i] 

Store_Item[1] = new Store_Item{name: 'blabla', cost{Costs:0}}; and so on, The problem is that i can't acces the object within Store_Item using the same line. else i couldve used : 

Store_Item[1] = new Store_Item {Name:"name", amount:0};
Store_Item[1].cost.Costs = 100;